# How to generate Detailed Report with metrics per each Transaction

Tags: java, jmeter

I am using Jmeter 4.0 and I have below properties in user.properties file (which are default ones as per https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html)

```
jmeter.reportgenerator.statistic_window = 2000
jmeter.reportgenerator.apdex_satisfied_threshold=1500
jmeter.reportgenerator.apdex_tolerated_threshold=3000
jmeter.reportgenerator.exporter.html.series_filter=^(Search|Order)(-success|-failure)?$
jmeter.reportgenerator.exporter.html.filters_only_sample_series=true
```

I notice that the jmeter article https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html has metrics per each Transaction in `APDEX` and `Statistics` tables as below

[image]
where as my report doesnt have metrics per each Transaction in `APDEX` and `Statistics` tables
[image]

can someone please help me to configure report to have metrics per each Transaction in `APDEX` and `Statistics` tables

Comment: You need the filtering of transactions?

Comment: @user7294900 yes, also I want to generate the report similar to the report in https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html

Answer (score 2):

You are copying example for specific sampler names

> below example we filter on Search and Order samples

You should change regex according to your sampler names, for example for Samplers MyT1 MyT2,... use

```
 jmeter.reportgenerator.exporter.html.series_filter=^(MyT)(-success|-failure)?$
```

If the label is not at the start of the sampler name use:

```
get regex using label, as `jmeter.reportgenerator.exporter.html.series_filter=(.*)MyT(.*)(-success|-failure)‌​?$`
```

Comment: my sampler names are like `1000_<label>` `2000_<label>``3000_<label>``4000_<label>``5000_<label>` so should I use `^(1|2|3|4|5)(-success|-failure)?$`

Comment: @RanPaul I think you better get regex using label, as `jmeter.reportgenerator.exporter.html.series_filter=(.*)<label>(.*)(-success|-failure)‌​?$`